# Since one HMActionSet can not be added to both HMHome and HMTrigger, how can I add a HMActionSet to HMTrigger?

Tags: ios8, xcode6, homekit

My code is:

```
// Create Action Set
[_myHome addActionSetWithName:@"Night" completionHandler:^(HMActionSet *actionSet, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Add action set");
    }
}];

// Create Time Trigger
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.second = 5;
HMTimerTrigger *timeTrigger = [[HMTimerTrigger alloc] initWithName:@"Night Trigger" fireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5] timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] recurrence:dateComponents recurrenceCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];

// Add Action Set to Trigger
for (HMActionSet *actionSet in _myHome.actionSets) {
    if ([actionSet.name isEqualToString:@"Night"]) {
        [timeTrigger addActionSet:actionSet completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }else {
                NSLog(@"Add Action Set to Trigger");
            }
        }];
    }
}

// Add Trigger to My Home
[_myHome addTrigger:timeTrigger completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Add Trigger");
    }
}];
```

First I add a HMActionSet called "Night" to HMHome. Then I add the same HMActionSet to HMTrigger. HomeKit throws an error: **Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error 12.)"** which means **ObjectAlreadyAssociatedToHome**.

My guess is that you can not add the same HMActionSet to both HMHome and HMTrigger. So I try create a HMActionSet and add it to HMTrigger, then add the HMTrigger to HMHome. But I've encounter a problem with creating the HMActionSet, since it can not be initiated.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the add trigger after the actionset was successfully added, meaning within the completion handler.

Comment: Also a note- firedate has to be rounded seconds. according to apple documentation: Timer triggers are only set at the beginning of a minute. Seconds are not used and an error will be returned if the fire date includes a seconds value other than 0. When the timer fires, it will typically fire within 1 minute of the scheduled fire date or calculated recurrence fire date, depending on system power and resource management.

Answer (score 0):

HMActionSet can be added to HMTrigger if its already added to home.

HMActionset is a Scene (which is a collection of writable characteristics of any Accessory).
Which can be executable with a single command.

So either one can just execute HMActionSet or It can be added to Trigger
To execute that Scene at certain times.

There should be two different views to handle HMActionSet (Add, rename, remove, change values of characteristic).

And for Triggers It will create a Trigger and "assign" the HMActionSet from the same home to that trigger.

However, you need to manage recurrence, firedate and enable property to work trigger perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

```
dateComponents.second = 5;
```

> Timer triggers are only set at the beginning of a minute. **Seconds are not used and an error will be returned if the fire date includes a seconds value other than 0.** When the timer fires, it will typically fire within 1 minute of the scheduled fire date or calculated recurrence fire date, depending on system power and resource management.

[According to Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HMTimerTrigger_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/HMTimerTrigger/fireDate)